# Why does dagger not fail at compile-time when a class in the injects clause cannot be injected?

Tags: java, module, runtime, compile-time, dagger

I have this class:

```
public class ClassWithoutInject {

}
```

... and this module ...

```
@Module(
        injects={
                ClassWithoutInject.class 
        })
public class SimpleModule {
}
```

Am I wrong in thinking that this should generate a compile-time error?  At run-time I get:

```
  Unable to create binding for com.example.ClassWithoutInject required by class com.example.SimpleModule
```

(Because the class doesn't have an @Inject-annotated constructor).  But shouldn't dagger know that at compile-time?

Comment: Do you have dagger-compiler on your classpath?

Comment: Yep.  (If I didn't, I believe it would say something about invalid module, are you sure code-generation was run).  If I add an @Inject-annotated constructor to that class all becomes well.

Comment: Oh, right. v1.1+ requires the use of the compiler... I'll have to try locally later. Or someone else might be able to help before then.

Comment: Am I correct though that this is an error?  I.e. you would expect that code to fail at compile time?

Comment: Seems like it should be to me.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you actually injecting `ClassWithoutInjects`?

The `injects` on the Module refers to classes that will request dependencies from the provided by that module.

So in this case, Dagger is expecting `ClassWithoutInjects` to request dependencies from the ObjectGraph, with dependencies provided by this module (which is currently empty).

If you wanted to provide `ClassWithoutInjects` as a dependency, and not as consumer of the dependencies (which is what it is setup as in the module), either add the `@Inject` on it's constructor, or add an explicit provider method in the module.

```
@Module
public class SimpleModule {
  @Provides ClassWithoutInjects provideClassWithoutInjects() {
    return new ClassWithoutInjects();
  }
}
```

If `ClassWithoutInjects` is a consumer of dependencies.

```
@Module(injects = ClassWithoutInjects.class)
public class SimpleModule {
  // Any dependencies can be provided here
  // Not how ClassWithoutInjects is not a dependency, you can inject dependencies from
  // this module into it (and get compile time verification for those, but you can't 
  // provide ClassWithoutInjects in this configuration
}

public class ClassWithoutInject {
    // Inject dependencies here
}
```

Comment: Yes, my question is not "why doesn't this code work" but rather "why doesn't it fail until runtime"